# Kubernetes can not get its own cluster IP

Tags: docker, kubernetes, microservices

I have 3 kubernetes services which are:

```
service 1:

name: abc

service 2:

name: def

service 3:

name: hgk
```

In application running on service 1, I successfully use environment variables to get cluster IP of other services.

```
System.getenv(DEF_SERVICE_HOST); --> success
System.getenv(HGK_SERVICE_HOST); --> success
```

However, when I call the service 1 's environemnet, it return null

```
System.get(ABC_SERVICE_HOST); ---> null
```

Looks like it can not get its own cluster IP.

Do you guys have any ideas?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The only service environment variables that are populated in a pod are the services that existed before the pod created. Environment variables are not injected into running pods once they've already been started.

I'm guessing that you created the `abc` replication controller / pods before you created the `abc` service. If you kill the existing pods and let them be recreated, they should have the ABC_SERVICE_HOST environment variable set.

Comment: yeah, exactly. That was the problem. Thank you!